# JIRA API in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, jira

Is there a JIRA API client (or library) written in Common Lisp (I use SBCL)? So far I was able to find the two (both in GitHub.com ):

- fiddewoaroof/jira-api
- deterministic-arts/DartsCLJiraApi

Having been restricted by my rather limited Common Lisp knowledge I was unable to ran none of the two above. The first throws an unhandled exception, the second one requires some initial ASDF tuning.

Needs are modest. Selecting issues, some simple filtering would be enough.

Comment: After quick setup of ASDF it was possible to start loading DartsCLJiraApi. Alas, missed dependences prevented me to proceed.
  Component darts.lib.trivia not found.

Comment: https://github.com/deterministic-arts/DartsCLTrivia I think this is the repository you are looking for. Unless you specifically avoid using Qucklisp, you'd be probably better off by getting your packages using it. If Quicklisp doesn't know about your package, just download it into `~/quicklisp/local-packages/<package-name>`.

Comment: Appreciate your help! Did as you advised. Alas, more missing components have found:
CL-USER> (asdf:load-system :darts.lib.jira-api)
; Evaluation aborted on Component "trivial-utf-8" not found, required by #<SYSTEM "darts.lib.jira-api">.
CL-USER>

Comment: If you installed Qucklisp, you can do: `(ql:system-apropos "utf-8")` and it should find two systems: `trivial-utf-8` and `trivial-utf-8-tests`. I think the first one is the one you are missing. https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/ here're the instructions for installing Quicklisp, if you need them.

Comment: Hey, I advise you update your question with your stacktrace. And if you have trouble installing Quicklisp, checkout [Portacle](https://shinmera.github.io/portacle/), it's built-in.

Comment: Thank you all! I tried to follow the path you have showed to me. Alas, stuck again...

(asdf:load-system :darts.lib.jira-api)
; Evaluation aborted on Component "darts.lib.hashtree" not found, required by
#<SYSTEM "darts.lib.jira-api">.

CL-USER> (ql:system-apropos "hashtree")
#<SYSTEM darts.lib.hashtree-test / dartsclhashtree-20150923-git / quicklisp 2017-04-03>
#<SYSTEM darts.lib.hashtrie / dartsclhashtree-20150923-git / quicklisp 2017-04-03>
#<SYSTEM darts.lib.wbtree / dartsclhashtree-20150923-git / quicklisp 2017-04-03>
Sorry , backtrace is much larger then the comment.